# Why is my loop looping just once even though there are 3 items?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The following code loops through files and output their names plus some xhtml:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var fs = require('fs'),
    files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/files/')

console.log(files.length)

var manifest = function() {
  for (let i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; ++i) {
    let contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/files/' + files[i], 'utf8')
    return `<item href="${files[i]}.html" id="html30" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>\n`
  }
}

console.log(manifest())
```

The output is this:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2n3/bin$ node content.js
<item href="foo1.txt.html" id="html30" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
```

Which is weird, because there are three files. `console.log(files.length)` outputs:

```
alex@alex-K43U:~/node/m2n3/bin$ node content.js
3
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `return` is breaking your loop :) I think this needs a logic re-think. It's a good scenario for a generator btw.

Comment: Probably you can store all your return item in an array inside the loop and then return it outside loop. `return` is breaking the loop hence it's showing only one item.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, `return` is going to exit your `manifest()` call immediately with the first value found.

This would seem to be a good use-case for some more ES6 features:

```js
// Enable const/let inside of node
"use strict";

const fs = require('fs'),
    files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/files/')

// Create a generator function so that the caller can iterate using for..of
const manifests = function*() {
  // for..of to iterate array contents directly, no need for a counter
  for (let fileName of files) {
    // Nothing actually done with contents - do you need it?
    let contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/files/' + fileName, 'utf8');
    // Use 'yield' instead of 'return' to say that we're done with this
    // iteration, the caller can choose to either exit or continue to the next
    yield `<item href="${fileName}.html" id="html30" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
`; // Newline will be parsed by the template string literal
  }
}

// for..of to iterate our manifests
for(const manifestXml of manifests()) {
  console.log(manifestXml);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement breaks your loop, you can store the values in an array and have your method return that array.

```
var manifest = function() {
  var arr[];
  for (let i = 0, l = files.length; i < l; ++i) {
    let contents = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/files/' + files[i], 'utf8')
    arr[i]= `<item href="${files[i]}.html" id="html30" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>\n`
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: In other words: `return files.map(...)` ;-)